# "Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I got this error when i send 2 parameter from jQuery to WebMethod and  using multiple params.

```
{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027haha\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

In jQuery:

```
$(".txtNoiDung").focusout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "QuanLyTin.aspx/test1cai",
            data: JSON.stringify({ hahas: $(this).val(),tuans: "hahaha" }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#vltxtNoiDung").text(msg.d)
            },
            error: function (xhr, reason, ex) {
                alert(reason);
            }
        });
    });
```

In code behind

```
 [WebMethod()]
        public static string test1cai(string haha, string tuan)
        {
            return "Hi, "+haha + tuan;
        }
```

How can i resolve it?
Thanks you guys.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your service is accepting parameters named `haha` and `tuan`, but your JavaScript is passing in `hahas` and `tuans`. Remove the "s" from both:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ haha: $(this).val(),tuan: "hahaha" }),
```

Also, keep in mind that these parameters much match between client- and server-side *with case-sensitivity*.

Answer (score 4):

Your JavaScript object property names must match the names of the parameters on the web service method so they can be bound appropriately. You currently have:

```
{ hahas: $(this).val(),tuans: "hahaha" }
```

which should probably be:

```
{ haha: $(this).val(), tuan: "hahaha" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing the same method parameter from the function in code behinedto, in your Ajax call

data: "{ 'haha': '" + "your data" + 'tuan': '" + "your data" + "' }"

- There shouldn't be any spaces like ' tuan '

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to use curly brackets while JSON.stringify({})
You have to use like this :

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify({ PrefrencesDetailEntity: PrefrencesDetailEntity
        contentType: "application/json;", //charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, jqXHR) {
        if (data !== null && data.Status === 201) {
        toastr.success("Your changes have been saved successfully");
                        }
                    }
});
and C# method would be like this :

[WebMethod]
        public static NotificationValues PostNotificationData(PrefrencesDetailEntity PrefrencesDetailEntity)
        {
 //your C# code logic
}