# Jquery call not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I am calling code behind function from JQuery. It is not even throwing any error and unable to find what the issue is. Here is my code.

```
$("#btnForwardSubmit").click(function () {
    var EmailAddress = document.getElementById('<%= txtForwardEmail.ClientID%>').value                
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ProposalEdit.aspx/ForwardEmail",
            data: "{Email:" + EmailAddress + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
            }                   
       });
     });
```

Code behind function is like this.

```
  Private Sub ForwardEmail(Email As String)
    If Email.Length > 0 Then

    End If
End Sub
```

I found it here. I am passing data atrribute wrong.

["Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032276/messageinvalid-web-service-call-missing-value-for-parameter-u0027)

Comment: If you trace the code, is `click` called? Does the element exist to get the value (line one of `click`)? Does an ajax call actually get sent (Use fiddler to check for what is getting sent too/from the server). These should get you started

Comment: @drew_w Yes, Click is called and I alert the EmailAddress. After stepping into $.Ajax, I am unable to debug and find the issue.

Comment: What does Fiddler or a similar tool show being sent to the server?

Comment: Make your function Public...  What does that do?

Comment: @webdad3 I tried that and it is not working

Comment: @Bingit what does your web tools say when the call to the ForwardEmail method?  200/300/400/500?

Comment: @webdad3 it gives 500 internal server erro in console.

Comment: @Bingit  check the URL it is trying to look at?  Does it make sense?

Comment: @webdad3 I am unable to test the URL. What is the best way to test it

Comment: @Bingit - in your web tools it should show you the URL it is trying to hit in your ajax call

Comment: @webdad3 It is the same page. I am calling the same page method.

Comment: @Bingit so you are on ProposalEdit.aspx and trying to call ProposalEdit.aspx?  And you are getting a 500 level error?  Try splitting it from that page and add a new one.

Comment: @webdad3 Yes, I am on the same and calling the function that is in aspx.VB file.  What do you mean by splitting from the page ?

Comment: @webdad3 This is the message I got while debug POST 500 application/json 1.57 KB 31 ms JS Library XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

ForwardEmail must be Public per webdad3, and must be decorated with the `<WebMethod>` attribute (in the `System.Web.Services` namespace).