# Message“:”Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027fff\u0027.“,”StackTrace

Tags: json

I have a js file.a want to pass a value as a json using ajax to my codebehind but I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lLYI.jpg)

> Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter:
>   \u0027fff\u0027.","StackTrace

my javascript code is:

```
$('#Button2').click(function() {

    var edata = {};
    edata.Eid = $('#txteid').val();
    edata.Ename = $('#txtname').val();
    edata.Dob = $('#txtdob').val();
    edata.slary = $('#txtsalary').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "Call1.asmx/SaveEmployee",

        method: "post",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: '{Emp:' + JSON.stringify(edata) + '}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() {},
        error: function(x, e) {
            alert('error is ' + e);

            alert(x.responseText);
            alert(x.status);
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032276/messageinvalid-web-service-call-missing-value-for-parameter-u0027

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032276/messageinvalid-web-service-call-missing-value-for-parameter-u0027)

Comment: i am sending all parameter value but it gives error

Comment: `missing value for parameter: "fff"` Says that you are not sending value for `fff` parameter. Also I cannot see `fff` in above code.